# Ubuntu 12.04 biblatex mla style

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I've had a good search of internet and unable to find answer. I have Ubuntu 12.04 with all updates, and using LyX for work/study. I need to use `mla` style for some papers. There is no `biblatex-mla` style folder installed even though what I've found suggests that `mla` is part of the TeXLive install. I've downloaded the package and installed in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-mla`.
In preample, I have:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
```

When I try to view pdf output get:

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}

The bibliography style 'mla' could not be found.
```

I would appreciate any help please.

Answer (score 1):

You should not normally install into `/usr/share/texmf`, as this is the 'managed' part of the TeX system. Instead, you should normally put any 'personal' additions inside `~/texmf`, in the correct subdirectories. Anything added to `~/texmf` should then be picked up: if you do add to `/usr/share/texmf`, you will need to run `texhash` (I think with `sudo`) as the main installation tree is not searched directly but has a hashed database of files.